# Нужно ли выделять запятыми оборот "я бы сказал"?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы очень дорожим нашими сложившимися партнерскими, я бы сказал (,) даже дружескими отношениями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно.

Мы очень дорожим нашими сложившимися партнерскими И, я бы сказал, даже дружескими отношениями.

Я бы обязательно поставил И. Иначе "я бы сказал" можно отнести и к партнерским, и к дружеским.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаемый вариант: Мы очень дорожим нашими сложившимися партнерскими, я бы сказал даже, дружескими отношениями.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Встречается два варианта оформления подобных выражений, так как частицу "даже" можно отнести к вводному предложению или однородному члену, например:

Бывали очень хорошие, я бы сказал даже, по-настоящему радостные минуты,

Деревенька носит название совершенно особое, я бы сказал, даже символическое.

Для проверки можно убрать вводное предложение: Мы очень дорожим нашими сложившимися партнерскими, даже дружескими отношениями. Смысл не очень ясен, поэтому лучше отнести частицу к вводному предложению.