# Я бы даже сказал (?) вынуждает их

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Это позволяет мужьям (я бы даже сказал (?) вынуждает их) искать отношения на стороне.* Нужен ли здесь какой-нибудь знак препинания после ***я бы даже сказал***?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38979/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это позволяет мужьям (**я бы даже сказал,** вынуждает их) искать отношения на стороне.

Или: Это позволяет мужьям (**я бы даже сказал** – вынуждает их) искать отношения на стороне.

**Это вводное предложение** со значением уточнения значения, подбора нужного слова.

Здесь ***я бы даже сказал***  обособляется запятой или тире  внутри **вставной конструкции**. Но чаще используется вариант, когда  вводное  предложение вписывается в структуру предложения, при этом оно относится к уточняемому слову.

**Примеры** (с различными членами предложения):

1) Обособленное определение

Мы жили в весьма странном, **я бы даже сказал ― противоестественном**, мире нэпа, населённом призраками.

2) Однородные определения:

В общем, цирк ― во многом семейное, **я бы даже сказал**, корпоративное  дело.

Почему понадобилось целых 5 лет напряженнейшей, **я бы даже сказал,** сумасшедшей работы комиссии по борьбе с коррупцией ...

2) Именная часть сказуемого, союз И:

Объективы стали для него слабы и, **я бы даже сказал**, скучны.

3) Дополнение, союз И:

Но в этот раз она смотрела на меня совсем иначе ― с какой-то сломленной покорностью и, **я бы даже сказал**, мольбой..

Answer (score 4):

Нужен. Подойдет запятая, но возможно также и тире. Причина -- разные грамматические основы: 1) я бы (даже) сказал; 2) вынуждает.

Answer (score 1):

Без знака не получается: нарушается грамматика - предложения-то разные. 
Можно оформить как прямую речь либо просто через двоеточие.

> § 161. Двоеточие ставится после предложения, за которым следует одно
>   или несколько предложений, не соединенных с первым посредством cоюзов
>   и заключающих в себе:
>
> а) разъяснение или раскрытие содержания того, о чем говорится в первом
>   предложении, например:
>
> ```
> Я не ошибся: старик не отказался от предлагаемого стакана.
> Пушкин
>
> Сверх того, заботы большого семейства беспрестанно мучили ее:
> ```
>
> то кормление грудного ребенка не шло, то нянька ушла, то, как теперь,
>   заболел один из детей.
>       Л. Толстой
>
> ```
> Тут открылась картина довольно занимательная: широкая сакля,
> ```
>
> которой крыша опиралась на два законченных столба, была полна народа.
>       Лермонтов
>
> б) основание, причина того, о чем говорится в первом предложении,
>   например:
>
> ```
> Не нагнать тебе бешеной тройки: кони сыты, и крепки, и бойки.
> Некрасов
>
> Недаром боги греческие признавали над собою неотразимую власть
> ```
>
> судьбы: судьба – это была та темная граница, за которую не пepecтупало
>   сознание древних.
>       Белинский

(Правила-56)

Можно обсуждать, подходит ли наш пример под это правило (ну у Розенталя, ни у Лопатина именно таких примеров на двоеточие нет), но на практике им пользуются.

Для тире или запятой не вижу оснований.

Наверное все-таки бесспорным вариантом будет двоеточие и кавычки.

***Это позволяет мужьям (я бы даже сказал: "вынуждает их") искать
отношения на стороне.***

Comment: Откуда кавычки? Там и намека не было на прямую речь или нечто ей подобное.

Comment: @М_Г а что, собственно, тут мешает признать прямой речью? Поставить "что" - получите косвенную. С вводным же сочетанием "я бы сказа" такие штуки проходят с трудом. Мне так с трудои представляется, как обосновать иное, если оппонент упрется. На самом деле здесь "я бы сказал" вводное, Но я нашел всего лишь один пример в нацкорпусе со скобками, совсем не бесспорный. Смотрится плохо. При этом запятая внутри скобок совсем не бесспорна. Вот так и приходится искать какой-то паллиатив.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423029  Вот обсуждение этой проблемы, но там и пример был зрительно попроще. А кавычки - для того, чтобы сделать "слова" автора единым членом предложения.